# I want to display data of attendance collection, how to display it?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

Users collection having a another collection which is attendance. And i want to display data of attendance collection. How will i display that data? I am using Angular7[image]

```
        this.afs.collection('users')
            .doc(this.userId)
            .collection('attendance')
            .get()
            .subscribe(function(querySnapshot) {
                  querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=> {
                     console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data()); 
                     attendance= doc.data()
                     console.log(attendance);
          });
      });
```

this code snippet is used for getting all data and it is displaying on console also.

```
      <div class="row" *ngIf="(user$ | async) as user">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <p>User Name: <strong>{{user.name}}        </strong></p>
                            <p>Date : <strong>{{todayNumber | date}}</strong></p>
                            <p>Punch In Time: <strong>{{punchIn | date:'mediumTime'}}</strong></p>
                            <p>Punch Out Time: <strong>{{punchOut | date:'mediumTime'}}</strong></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

this code is showing username and date.

Comment: add the code you tried with [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: added code i tried @Allabakash

Comment: what does it printed in the console for attendance and in html  what does **user** contains ? is it same as attendance ?

Comment: on console it displays the that punchInTime and PunchOutTime as it is. And user used for showing name of user which is a field of 'users' collection

Comment: @TriveniMali is it `punchIn`, `punchOut`? or as displayed in your image `punchInTime` and `punchOutTime`?

Comment: @NimittShah it is punchIn, punchOut. I used both for storing current time

Comment: i also want to find time difference between from both timestamp. How to do that?